# WCF Data Service, don't expose all columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

My WCF Data Service is bound to an EDMX, which contains certain columns I don't want to expose through the Data Service. How do I hide those columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`[IgnoreProperties]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.ignorepropertiesattribute.aspx) attribute if you're using Data Services version 5:

```
[IgnoreProperties("Email", "Password")]
public partial class User 
{

}
```

Comment: This is only for reflection provider, this won't going to work with EF Provider

Comment: If so, any alternatives?